# How to avoid the change of timestamp of files when moving then from directory

Tags: files

When I move files from one directory to another, the timestamp of the files changes. For example, if the file was created with  a date 2013-01-01, when I move it to a different directory, the final file will have the date of the move, not of the creation.

How to fix this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior. When I move a file its creation date doesn't change, even when I rename the file.

Comment: i am using ubuntu version: 12.10. I take photos using a digital camera with a micro sd. I unplug it from the camera and insert into a card ready on the computer with ubuntu. Then i copy it to a shared windows server 2000 folder. The files end with changed date.

Answer (score 5):

- `cp -r -p SOURCE DESTINATION`
- `cp -r --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps SOURCE DESTINATION`

These two commands do the same thing.  The Second allows you to chose what remains the same.  I am not aware of a way of specifically doing this with `mv`, but I believe this is `mv`s default behavior.

Alternatively, you could try copying **hard-links**, which is much more similar to `mv`, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/220202/how-to-mv-a-folder-in-linux-retaining-its-mtime):

- `cp -p -r -l source/date target/`

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to an ntfs/fat partition?  If this is true, try setting up a rule in */etc/fstab* that uses your uid.

Comment: but to be user friend, i would prefer that the nautilus in ubuntu did that. It is not pratical to make a command line everytime i need to copy files. More suggestions?